# Filter Pivot in Report Filter for a range of values

Tags: excel, pivot

I have the following issue. I have large dataset with product codes, dates at which they are shipped and their tranport method.
I would like to create a pivot of the product code on the left and their transport method on the top. But as variable I would the pivot to only present a range of dates. These dates are presented in the form yyyyww. (example: from 201420 to 201505). 
I have a column where each of the individual year and weeknumber as presented, so they could be looked up from there. This also allows it to be a variable.
How can I get this pivot to present this information between a date range?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2010 and later you can insert a slicer for any field in the data source and click the values in the slicer that you want to include in the pivot table. Shift click to select contiguous slicer values, Ctrl-click to pick non-contiguous slicer items.

As an alternative to slicers, you can drag the desired filter columns into the filter pane.

The screenshot shows the column names in the filter pane and how the filters appear above the pivot table.  It also shows slicers to the right of the pivot table. A pivot table in Excel 2010 and later can have both filters and slicers. Earlier versions can only have filters.

[image]

The following screenshot shows what happens when values have been clicked on the slicers. These selected slicer values are mirrored in the filter settings (and vice versa). So, a slicer is just a user-friendly way to select one or more filters for the pivot table.

Please note that you would normally only use one method: either slicer OR filters. Choose the one that you like most.

[image]